# Swift AWSMobileClient getTokens not working after federatedSignIn

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, facebook-login

```
AWSMobileClient.default().federatedSignIn(providerName: IdentityProvider.facebook.rawValue, token: (result?.token!.tokenString)!, completionHandler: { (userState, error) in
if let error = error{
    print("Initialize Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}else{
    print("User State: ", userState!)//User State:  signedIn
    switch (userState) {
    case .signedIn?:
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.getAWSToken()
        }
    default:
        print("Sign In needs info which is not et supported.")
    }
}
})  
func getAWSToken(){
    AWSMobileClient.default().getTokens { (result, error) in
        if error == nil{
            print("JWT Token: ", (result?.idToken?.tokenString!)!)
            print("Expire : ", (result?.expiration!)!)
            AppData.sharedInstance.JWT_Token = (result?.idToken?.tokenString!)! as String
            AppData.sharedInstance.Refresh_Token = (result?.refreshToken?.tokenString!)! as String
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"
            let dtStr = dateFormatter.string(from: (result?.expiration!)!)
            let expireDate =  Utility.UTCToLocal(date: dtStr)
            AppData.sharedInstance.JWT_Token_Expire_Date = expireDate
            UserDefaults.standard.set(AppData.sharedInstance.JWT_Token_Expire_Date, forKey: Utility.KEY_JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRE_DATE)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(AppData.sharedInstance.JWT_Token, forKey: Utility.KEY_JWT_Token)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(AppData.sharedInstance.Refresh_Token, forKey: Utility.KEY_Refresh_Token)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.getUserInfo()
                RSApiManager.shared.postDeviceToken(dToken: Utility.MY_TOKEN)
            }
        }else{
            print("Error: ", error.debugDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

AWSMobileClient.default().getTokens always shows

> "Error: 
>   Optional(AWSMobileClient.AWSMobileClientError.notSignedIn(message:
>   "User is not signed in, please sign in to use this API."))"

even it shows success "User State:  signedIn" for federateSignIn.

```
AWSMobileClient.default().signIn(username: username, password: password) { (signInResult, error) in
self.getAWSToken() 
}
```

It is working fine after signIn() but not for federateSignIn().

Answer (score 0):

**This is expected behavior in your use-case.**

If you want JsonWebTokens from the Cognito UserPool, you have to use a non-federated authentication method like `.showSignIn()` or `.signIn()`; those operate directly against the Cognito UserPool.

A Federated Identity provider can not get you Cognito JsonWebTokens because those tokens come directly from the Cognito UserPool; they don't come from something like the Cognito IdentityPool.

**AWS's Amplify Documentation states:**

> *...if the user is signed in via `.federatedSignIn` to a Cognito IdentityPool, only `.identityId` and AWS credentials for authenticated role will be available, and `.getTokens()` will return `AWSMobileClientError.notSignedIn` error.*

This excerpt is under the documentation's heading of ['State Tracking > signedIn'](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/auth/how-it-works/q/platform/ios/#state-tracking)  found here.